# Error when testing return value of decorator

Tags: python

I am trying to test my understanding of wrapper functions so built this code

```
def wrapper():
    print ("Wrapper")
    def wrapped():
        print ("Wrapped")
    return wrapped 

if int (wrapper()):
    print ("Returned integer")
```

I tried `if str(wrapper())` and `if callable (wrapper())` and it was OK

I don't understand why the `if int (wrapper())` yields an error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'function'
```

Surely it should just say False and not have an error at all?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `if int(...)`? What are you testing for? ... https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what exactly you are testing, but I can try to explain what your code does.

**Case 1: `if str(wrapper())`**

1. When calling `wrapper()` it prints "Wrapper" and then returns a function called `wrapped`.
2. So calling `str(wrapper())` is equivalent to `str(wrapped)`. Notice that there are no parentheses after `wrapped`. This means the argument of the `str` function is a **function object**.

   When calling `str` on a **function object** it returns a string with the functions name and position in memory. Check this example:

```py
>>> def test():
...     pass
... 
>>> str(test)
'<function test at 0x7fa95c504668>'
>>> type(str(test))
<type 'str'>
```

3. So `if str(wrapper())` will evaluate to `if '<function wrapped at 0x7fa95c504668>'`.
4. For all non-empty strings the if statement gets executed. Look at this example:

```py
>>> if "string":
...     print("Non empty string")
... 
Non empty string
>>> if "":
...     print("This line will not be printed")
... 
>>>
```

**Case 2: `if callable(wrapper())`**

1. same as before
2. `callable` checks if an object has an `__call__` attribute
3. Calling `callable(wrapper())` is equivalent to `callable(wrapped)`. As `wrapped` is a function it has the `__call__` attribute and the expression evaluates to `True`.
4. So `if callable(wrapper())` evaluates to `if True` and the if statement will get executed!

**Case 3: `if int(wrapper())`**

1. same as before
2. `int` can **only** convert numbers and strings to integers.
3. `int(wrapper())` is equivalent to `int(wrapped)`. So you are trying to call `int` with a **function object**!
4. `int` cannot convert a **function object** to an integer and gives the arrow message:

```py
Exception has occurred: TypeError
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'function'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Decorator is just a fancy name for a function that takes a function as argument, and returns a function. So an example of decorator is:

```
def wrapper(func):
    print ("Wrapper")
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        print ("Wrapped")
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped 

@wrapper
def to_wrap():
    print("decorated function")
```

which if you run `to_wrap()`, you are actually running the `wrapped()` with variable `func` equals to `to_wrap`.

So having this idea in mind, let's look at your code:

```
if int (wrapper()):
    print ("Returned integer")
```

what `wrapper()` returns is a function (both in your code or in my modification above) and then you try to convert that into `int` and check its boolean value. This conversion is not implemented and thus Python raise TypeError, for an object of *function type* cannot be converted into integer type.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The decorator still needs to be called. What you have right now is a *closure*, which returns a function:

```py
def f():
    def wrapped():
         return 10
    return wrapped

x = f()
# x is the function 'wrapped'
```

Note that this did not call `wrapped`, it simply returned it. You will need to call `x` to change this behavior:

```py
x()
10

# Which is implicitly calling wrapped() to return 10
```

The decorator syntax takes care of this for you:

```py
def f(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper # still returns an un-called function

@f
def x():
    return 10

x()
# 10
```

Where the `@f` will effectively do `f(x())`. Because you didn't call the function, you never got the returned type, so `int` raises a `TypeError`.

In your example explicitly:

```py
def wrapper():
    print("wrapper")
    def wrapped():
        print("wrapped")
        return "1" # you need to return a value here, otherwise it will return None
    return wrapped

int(wrapper()())
# wrapper
# wrapped
# 1
```

Notice the extra parentheses after `wrapper` is called, which calls `wrapped`. Also, if you don't return a value from `wrapped`, then you will return `None`, which will raise a different `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'`

Comment: Thanks for your help!